# In emacs while using M-x replace-regex, the expression matches except when i put a ^ and $ at the beginning and end. This is confusing to me!

Tags: regular-expressions

The search query is : ([\s]*print)[^(](.*)

It matches, BUT when I put ^ and $ like this :
^([\s]*print)[^(](.*)$, it doesn't.

Again both work in search-forward-regex but the 2nd one does not work in replace-regex. I was curious about this behavior

Comment: Down-voting because the question is useless when you haven't shown what you're trying to match. The regexp matches what it should match. We've no idea what you *think* it should match.

Comment: If you pay attention, I mean whatever matches is not the main concern. Once it matches, it should redundantly match when I put ^ in the beginning and $ at the end. The match failed when I did so - - this was confusing to me. I was trying to match:"   print whatever\n" -- \n meaning newline. Such sentences where the beginning may have whitespace, and end is newline. Thanks!

Comment: "where the beginning may have whitespace" will not match `^(` so that's one problem/misunderstanding, and why I said you needed to provide this information.

Comment: I think there is additional confusion, mind you. `([\s]print)` matches the text `(\print)` and `(sprint)`, and I'm not sure that's your intent. (n.b. I'm assuming you're calling `search-forward-regexp` interactively).

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. I understand now --  I am new to this. After I used \s-* for whitespace it worked. I used  [^(]  to mean that immediately after print there should not be (. Because I had two kinds of print: print("x") and print "x". Wanted to replace the former. I did not have any other format of print like print (), etc so I used very strict match. Nevamind it works now. I could edit the question but that would make the answers misleading so I will leave it like that! thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by `[\s]*`? If you want to match zero or more whitespace in Emacs, use

```
\s-*
```

as documented in [Backslash in Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html).

For example, the regex

```
^\(\s-*print\)[^(]\(.*\)$
```

matches

```
 printf(blah)
```